# Why is my search bar not showing results?

Tags: php, html, mysql, jquery-mobile

I have made a php search bar before, which worked fine. However, I have recently been developing a one-file web app using the jQuery mobile framework. The aim is to be able to search for a certain trade, person or business, but the results are not showing up. If you search, and there are no results, the message in the output variable prints "There are no results" on the page. The code for the search bar is below:

```
if(isset($_POST['search'])){
$searchq = $_POST['search'];
$searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i", "", "$searchq");

$squery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE name LIKE '%$searchq%' OR fname LIKE '%$searchq%' OR lname LIKE '%$searchq%' OR trade LIKE '%$searchq%' LIMIT 10") or die("Could not search");
$counts = mysql_num_rows($squery);
$output = '';
$outputs = '';

if($counts != 0){
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($searchq)){
        $ids = $row['id'];
        $fnames = $row['fname'];
        $lnames = $row['lname'];
        $trades = $row['trade'];
        $abouts = $row['about'];
        $emails = $row['email'];
        $numbers = $row['number'];
        $names = $row['name'];

        $output .= '<div>'.$trades.' '.$ids.'</div>';
    }
}else{
    $output = 'Sorry there were no results'; 
    }

}
```

I print this to the page with:

```
<h1><?php print($output); ?></h1>
```

It may also be worth noting that the first feature using php (the sign up form) worked perfectly, but the login form on the  same page didn't, and neither does the search bar; I am wondering if having different forms on the same page accessing the same database may cause some kind of problem. If anyone requires any more code, just leave a comment. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please don't use mysql* anymore. Switch to mysqli

Comment: Where could I learn this. Do you know of any decent tutorials as I have found a very clear video series for mysql

Comment: You need to know how to debug the sql query.  Figure out how to display it and then make sure it works using your sql console.

Comment: Have you tried checking with $counts > 0 or $counts !== 0, rather than $counts != 0, and print_r(mysql_fetch_array($searchq)) to confirm that there are in fact no results?

Comment: I have tried the greater than sign but wht does print_r do?

Comment: It echoes the resulting array data to the page. If you want it to look pretty, you could try echo '<code><pre>'.print_r(mysql_fetch_array($searchq),true).'</pre></code>'

Answer (score 0):

`$searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i", "", "$searchq");` Should be `$searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i", "", $searchq);`

i guess this would work fine now.
https://www.php.net/preg_replace last one should be a variable containing a string and not a string it self.

Comment: user3655857 Thanks for the quick reply but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: have you checked so your query actaully work without $searchq?

Comment: There should be no difference in the resulting value between "$searchq" and $searchq, though, confused as to why "$searchq" would have been used in the first place.

Comment: What do you mean without $searchq

Comment: a simple query displaying all the rows without the arguments

Comment: Thank you al for your suggestion, but I found my mistake. In the while loop, I put mysql_fetch_array($searchq), instead of $squery

Answer (score 0):

I think you may use `==` instead of one `=`. Please make the change and tell me if it works. It should look like this

```
if($counts ! == 0)
```

Comment: No luck I just get an  error saying 'undefined !' or something to that effect

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '!' in /home/a8901943/public_html/index.php on line 90 user2848973

Comment: You can't separate ! from the conditional.